# HP sfp+ nic in non HP server?(a normal desktop pc)

Tags: networking, hp, nic, sfp

Searched the web, no idea
I want to use nc560sfp+ hp nic in a normal pc,
the datasheet says the bus is pcie gen 2 , but I dont understand why it has compatible part?
If it is pcie shouldn't it fit in any bus with minimum bandwidth needed, provided?
Any note or advice is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

It's just an Intel® 82599 controller. It will work using the ixgbe driver.

Comment: Thanks, great to here that, im going to use it on asus z170 mobo, but why datasheet says it is compatible with poliant gen 8 for example? Just for more knowledge and further clearance.

Comment: Because HP expects that people buy original HP parts to use them in  HP equipment. Their business doesn't really cater to other types of customers in that regard. They're unlikely to test and certify components for use in Dell servers I recon...

Comment: @HBruijn, thank you, so to put it differently, it means those will with the list in data sheet, and there is no guaranty that they work with else hardware out there, just like Qvl in Ram.